# I want to remove all the item in the array except the last item push in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

This is the example of the array

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

I expect to have this kind of result

```
arr = [5];
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Please read and apply the following instructions [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question! If you improve your question, you improve your chances for us to help you!

Comment: `arr = [arr.pop()];`?

Comment: you can use `slice` method : `arr.slice(arr.length - 1)`

Comment: thank you for the advice, in my next question in the future I will follow your advice @DouwedeHaan

Comment: @Rajesh I haven't try any thing yet, I just ask right  away , hehehe

Comment: @MariaJen please next time before you post a question, do give an effort your self. Use google to search and then try on your own. If then, you are stuck somewhere, post a question

Comment: @Rajesh okey thank you :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use **Splice/Slice** function as below:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr = arr.slice(-1);
console.log(arr);
```

**OR**

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr = arr.splice(arr.length - 1,1);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: `arr = arr.slice(arr.length - 1);` would be the better choice.

Comment: @str, yes you can also use it

Comment: Just `arr = arr.slice(-1)` would do.

Comment: thank you for your answer it really works!!